# Are questions on how to organize RPG equipment discoraged?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[How to organize my 3.X collection based on WotC's internal numbering system?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/organizing-my-collection-of-dd-3e-3-5-rulebooks) is in danger of being closed due to being non-constructive.

Similar questions like: [What’s an organized storage solution found for miniatures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/whats-an-organized-storage-solution-found-for-miniatures) and [What's an organized storage solution for Dungeon Tiles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1041/whats-an-organized-storage-solution-for-dungeon-tiles) had a decent run back in the early days of the site.

Is this a category of question that should now be discouraged?

Comment: It should be noted that the organization of 3.X books question has been reworded to be on-topic and has since garnered no more VtCs.

Comment: Yes, I saw that :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is a false comparison.

The question "how do I arrange books on a shelf?" is fundamentally different then "how do I best store some other object?".

One is asking for advice on sorting. The other is asking for equipment recommendations and methods that are far more meaningful then just the proper order to alphabetize.

Comment: relevant image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BngZk.png just replace "programmers" with "Role-Playing Gamers"

Comment: @Jeff thats what we are aiming for. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

My take is that since for these questions:

- there is (potentially) value to be found in the answers.
- answers can be based on personal experience.
- the answers are unlikely to devolve into either a chat, a debate or a war.

That it doesn't meet the "non constructive" criteria.

Comment: Does it have the potential to devolve into a list? Yes. It is very subjective at that. How do you organize your books? If everyone answered there would be hundreds of answers without a correct solution, it's so subjective that there is not value (at least for a Q&A site) according to the FAQ.

Comment: @GPierce The FAQ makes no mention of lists, and the only mention of subjective is that we should keep subjective opinions out of questions and answers. An answer that is "I sort my X in such and such a way, which works because of Y" seems to fit with what is encouraged in that section of the FAQ. Is there something missing from the FAQ about this, or guidelines from the stack exchange people about this that I am missing?

Comment: I apologize, I thought it was in the FAQ but it was actually decided in a previous meta thread, found here: (http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/176/should-we-allow-list-collection-questions)

Comment: It goes beyond the meta thread. List questions in general are not recommended on the SE network. At one time, this included a note in the FAQ, but it appears to have dropped out with the latest revision. You can read more here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/